Why does $W_1$ cancel out when $W_1$ perpendicular to the surface and Normal Force cancel out?
I recently learned that the weight that goes straight down drops out of the equation when you cancel the weight perpendicular to the Force Normal. I don't get what allows a person to drop the original weight when the perpendicular weight is canceled out using the Force Normal. Can someone explain?
(for example, if one was solving for T, W1 perpendicular to the surface would cancel out with N1, and W1 would cancel out leaving you only with W1 parallel to the surface and T... Why does W1 drop out? heard something about vectors canceling out but didn't get it.)


If you put your finger between the block and the wedge you’d quickly realize that the weight of the block doesn’t “cancel out”

There is nothing dropping out. You are misunderstanding the physics that is being told to you.
$$
\begin{align}
\tag1\vec{\mathcal W}&=+\vec{\mathcal W_\perp}+\vec{\mathcal W_\parallel}\\
\tag2\vec{\mathcal N}&=-\vec{\mathcal W_\perp}\\
\tag3\sum\vec{F}=\vec{\mathcal W}+\vec{\mathcal N}&=\vec{\mathcal W_\parallel}
\end  {align}$$
That is, when you add the weight and the normal reaction force together, a part of the weight is cancelled out. There is no dropping out. The person teaching you is trying to tell you that the result is equivalent to just ignoring the perpendicular part of the weight, so that you can save yourself some calculation headaches if you would just concentrate on the parallel part of the weight.

Ignoring the 2nd object on the right, if I am solving for T, would everything cancel out except the weight that is parallel to the surface and T?
making the equation so it would be ∑F = T-W∥

Yes, that is the point of what the person is trying to tell you.

One thing I have found helpful is to remember that when we say "cancel out," we typically actually mean that two things sum to 0.  Its easy to think of "cancel out" as being some clever physical property and thinking that it's something complicated to understand, when it's really just saying that some things equal 0.

The key is in the interaction of the block and the surface, while they are in contact.
The surface applies a "supporting" force to the block (the "Force Normal" N), and this force depends on the situation.

The force is perpendicular to the surface, directed away from the surface.
The force's value is "just enough" to keep the block from sinking into the surface, but not more, as otherwise the block would lift off, breaking the interaction.

(In cases with friction, things get a bit more complex, as the interaction then has another component, parallel to the surface, but I understand your question to be about friction-less interaction.)
So, the argumentation is:

If you add all forces applied to the block, the resulting force must have a zero component perpendicular to the surface, as otherwise the block would start to sink into the surface or to lift off from the surface.
In "all forces", there is one unknown force, the supporting force. We know its direction, but not its value.
Its value must be such that we get a resulting force with a zero perpendicular component.

We do:

Calculate the vector sum of all other forces applied to the block (e.g. gravity).
Compute its components parallel to the surface and perpendicular to the surface.
Then the supporting force will be just the opposite of the perpendicular force.
As resulting force on the block, only the parallel component remains, the perpendicular component and the supporting force cancel out one another.
In fact, as the perpendicular component gets compensated by the supporting force, there's no need to really calculate it.

So, "the weight that goes straight down drops out of the equation" is correct, but just takes this reasoning for granted.
